Function can not be called inside origin in cypress
`const searchFlight = async () => {
cy.get('#sel-departure-0').should('be.visible', 'Abreise').type('FRA');
}
if (Preprod === url.preprod_url_de) {
  cy.origin('www.example.com', () => { 
    searchFlight();
  })
} 

else {
  searchFlight(); 
}`

I have a program here. Wher I have to create function first and call it in if and else. This works fine in else, How ever it does not work in if. Because i am using Origin there. and It says.
You can not call function inside the origin.
Any solution?
The Error message is :
"Variables must either be defined within the cy.origin() command or passed in using the args option.
Using require() or import() within the cy.origin() callback is not supported. Use Cypress.require() to include dependencies instead, but note that it currently requires enabling the experimentalOriginDependencies flag"
How can I call the function in origin ?

The technical answer to this is to use Cypress.require to invoke the function both inside and outside the cy.origin().
First move the function to an external support file, since require() requires a file to load.
/cypress/support/utils.js
export const searchFlight = () => { 
  cy.get('#sel-departure-0').should('be.visible').type('FRA');
}

Then require() it both inside and outside the cy.origin()
const {searchFlight} = require('../support/utils.js')

if (...) {
  cy.origin('www.example.com', () => { 
    const {searchFlight} = Cypress.require('../support/utils.js')
    searchFlight();
  })
} else {
  searchFlight(); 
}


The real answer is - why are you using cy.origin() for this?
You should be changing the URL in cy.visit(url) instead.
